# Python time conditional while loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I need to read a variable from a file every 10 seconds until this variable 
`var != "0"` at which point I want to stop the loop.

So I'm trying to do a while loop with `time.sleep` to check the file but I cannot modify `var` outside the loop as it's only changing within the while loop:

```
while var == "0":
    file =open("/net/live.txt", "r")
    var = file.read()
    file.close()    
    if var == "0":
        time.sleep(10)  #wait 10 seconds and query again        
    else:
        file2 =open("/net/live2.txt", "w")
        file2.write(var)
        file2.close()
        time.sleep(10)
        print var       #var is unequal "0" so stop while loop
```

Comment: var == "0" is different to var == '0"'

Comment: yes sorry that was a typo its fixed now

Comment: So if `var` is not zero you want to stop the loop and write the value to a different file? Also, what did you want to do to `var` outside the loop?

Comment: So if var is not zero you want to stop the loop and write the value to a different file?   .. exactly      Also, what did you want to do to var outside the loop? as you said i really just want to write it to a file if its not 0

Comment: var is getting fetched with urllib from parsing a cnbc html (the opening course of the vix index...s&p500 volatility index) when the us stockmarket opens. sadly cnbc is not very reliable with updating it  so often i end up with a 0 as open. and i want to retry querying untill i got the right open course. this process is scheduled for every day with pythons schedule library.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Unix, you could use the signal module:

```
import signal, sys

# your function as signal handler
def handler(signum, frame):
    with open("/net/live.txt", "r") as file
        var = file.read()
        file.close()    
    if var != '0':
        with open("/net/live2.txt", "w") as file2
            file2.write(var)
            file2.close()
            print var

# install handler
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)

# emit SIGALRM after 10 secs
signal.setitimer(signal.ITIMER_REAL, 10)

# do other stuff
i = 1
while True:
    if i % 100000 == 0:
        print i
    i += 1
```

this should do what you expect. you can read more about signals here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html

**Windows** users will have to use one of the existing libraries in windows itself, i.e. the multimedia libraries supply timing functions and [here if found an implementation](http://osdir.com/ml/python.ctypes/2007-11/msg00024.html) from another developer.

Comment: @sk1982 added link to windows sample using multimedia library, hope that can help and if yes feel free to check this answer :)

Comment: @sk1982 btw. i optimized your reading from file. If you use the `with open(filename,'r') as file:` then you can assure, that the following code is only executed, if open does not fail

Comment: ah cool didnt know this. i usually do try with IO Error exceptions. thanks

Comment: @sk1982 exceptions are good to use here to, because i still have no error handling here in the code, but the `with open(...` with the following indented commands makes the code more readable because the file specific commands are "grouped"